# How to disable google sheet interaction while Apps Script is running?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have script which hides some of the sheets from a workbook to generate PDF from specific sheet then the unhides all the sheets after execution. The problem is that I do not want the user to interact with the  workbook while the script is running because the script hides & unhides sheet.

Is there any solution that I can disable the workbook interactions until the script ends?

I tried to protect the workbook while the script is running but it causes problem and increase the execution time.

Comment: Run the script from another workbook or make it standalone.  Not sure what you are trying to accomplish so it's difficult to guess what is appropriate for your case

Comment: I have 7 sheets in workbook. And in my script I generate PDF from 3rd sheet of workbook.  I could not find any way to just take the 3rd sheet only and generate PDF from that, so I have to first hide other 6 sheets then Generate PDF.  Then the script just simply unhides all the sheets after it generated the PDF file and save it in google drive.

Comment: What I want , In process of hiding and unhiding process of script I put an alert box or something like that which disable all the interactions for workbook.

Comment: You are going to have to explain that a little more thoroughly because I know of no way to disable spreadsheet interactions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to disable all the spreadsheet interactions while a script is running.

You could

- use the Lock Service to "disable" the interactions done by other scripts
- change Editors to Viewers and once the script finish the tasks that requires  that interactions be locked, change them back to Editors